# How To Change An Active Tab In DNN From Code-Behind?

Tags: c#, tabs, dotnetnuke, code-behind

On the admin side of my DotNetNuke website, I have two tabs with a few controls. I have also a grid view control on Tab 1 with a few records from the SQL server database i.e. Default Images & Slider Images. Each of the grid view row on Tab 1 also has an Edit button which fills the required textboxes (Image Title, Path, and URL, etc) of Tab 1 with data from that particular row in the code-behind.

When the user clicks on the edit button, an `if statement` on the code-behind file will check the type of the selected image. If it is a Slider Image, then it's title and URL will be passed to those particular textboxes on Tab 1.

However, if it is a Default Image, then I want to activate Tab 2 and pass the Title, Path, and URL of this default image those specific textboxes on Tab 2.

Is there any way to handle this from c# (code-behind)? Can I mark these tabs something like server controls, so I can easily get them with c# and activate the Tab 2? Any help will highly be appreciated.

Here is an illustration of the Tabs markup I am currently working on.

```
<div class="dnnForm dnnModuleSettings dnnClear" id="dnnAcProjectsModuleSettings">
<ul class="dnnAdminTabNav dnnClear">
    <li><a href="#A">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#B">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
    <div id="A" class="HomeRoomSlider">
        <div class="mspsContent dnnClear">
            <fieldset>
                //Controls etc
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="B" class="HomeRoomSliderDefault">
        <div class="mspsContent dnnClear">
            <fieldset>
                //Controls etc
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you even need a 2nd tab? It seems the first tab has all the controls to display info for each row to be edited.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Actually both the images are of a different type. They are added into the database using these separate tabs using two different methods for the purpose of saving a bool value of 1 with `Default Images` with the help of Method A, and a bool value of 0 with `Slider Images` with the help of Method B.

Comment: I would think you would probably want to do this client side with Javascript instead of server side?

Comment: What if user manually click on tab header before or after changing tab?